# Need to flatten nested JSON file using PySpark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark and trying to flatten JSON file using Pyspark but not getting desired output.

Here is my JSON file :-

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "event_name": "start",
            "event_properties": ["property1", "property2", "property3"],
            "entities": ["entityI", "entityII", "entityIII"],
            "event_timestamp": "2022-05-01 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "stop",
            "event_properties": ["propertyA", "propertyB", "propertyC", "propertyD"],
            "entities": ["entityW", "entityX", "entityY", "entityZ"],
            "event_timestamp": "2022-05-01 01:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want output using PySpark :-

```
event_name | event_properties | entities  | event_timestamp

start      | property1        | entityI   | 2022-05-01 00:00:00

start      | property2        | entityII  | 2022-05-01 00:00:00

start      | property3        | entityIII | 2022-05-01 00:00:00

stop       | propertyA        | entityW   | 2022-05-01 01:00:00

stop       | propertyB        | entityX   | 2022-05-01 01:00:00

stop       | propertyC        | entityY   | 2022-05-01 01:00:00

stop       | propertyD        | entityZ   | 2022-05-01 01:00:00
```

The code which I have tried :-
Implementing JSON File in PySpark

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("PySpark Read JSON") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(r"C:\Users\Lajo\Downloads\spark_ex1_input.json")

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer,col


def flatten(df):
   # compute Complex Fields (Lists and Structs) in Schema   
   complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   while len(complex_fields)!=0:
      col_name=list(complex_fields.keys())[0]
      print ("Processing :"+col_name+" Type : "+str(type(complex_fields[col_name])))
    
      # if StructType then convert all sub element to columns.
      # i.e. flatten structs
      if (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == StructType):
         expanded = [col(col_name+'.'+k).alias(col_name+'_'+k) for k in [ n.name for n in  complex_fields[col_name]]]
         df=df.select("*", *expanded).drop(col_name)
    
      # if ArrayType then add the Array Elements as Rows using the explode function
      # i.e. explode Arrays
      elif (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == ArrayType):    
         df=df.withColumn(col_name,explode_outer(col_name))
    
      # recompute remaining Complex Fields in Schema       
      complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   return df
   
   
 df_flatten = flatten(df)
 
 df_flatten.show()
```

Can someone help?

Comment: is schema fixed ?

Comment: Yes. Schema is fixed

Answer (score 0):

So first we read the json file and import needed functions.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, posexplode, col,concat_ws

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("PySpark Read JSON") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(r"input.json")
```

When dealing with nested JSON structures in PySpark and needing to flatten arrays side-by-side, the traditional `explode` function can lead to incorrect combinations if not used cautiously.

The solution to this problem is to maintain a unique identifier for each event to keep track of exploded elements.
The `posexplode` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html) is very useful for this. This function not only explodes the array into separate rows but also provides the position (index) of each element in the original array.

```
# Explode the events
df_events = df.select(explode(col("events")).alias("events_data"))

# Create a unique event identifier
df_events = df_events.withColumn("event_id", concat_ws('_', "events_data.event_name", "events_data.event_timestamp"))

# Explode the event_properties with their index and keep the event_id
df_properties = df_events.select(
        "event_id",
        "events_data.event_name",
        "events_data.event_timestamp",
        posexplode("events_data.event_properties").alias("index", "event_properties")
    )

# Explode the entities with their index and keep the event_id
df_entities = df_events.select(
        "event_id",
        posexplode("events_data.entities").alias("index", "entities")
    )

# Join on the event_id and index
final_df = df_properties.join(df_entities, on=["event_id", "index"]).select(
        "event_name",
        "event_properties",
        "entities",
        "event_timestamp"
    )
final_df.show(truncate=False)
```

result:

```
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
|event_name|event_properties|entities |event_timestamp    |
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
|start     |property1       |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2       |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property3       |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA       |entityW  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB       |entityX  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC       |entityY  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD       |entityZ  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
+----------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
```

EDIT: added step by step [gist](https://gist.github.com/mamonu/77965b9b7d4255adb5ff5b8d259de0bc) that shows results at each step too.

Another similar way would be to do the following after reading the file:

```
# Explode the events
df_events = df.select(explode(col("events")).alias("events_data"))
df_events = df_events.select(
    col("events_data.event_name").alias("event_name"),
    col("events_data.event_timestamp").alias("event_timestamp"),
    col("events_data.event_properties").alias("event_properties"),
    col("events_data.entities").alias("entities")
)
df_events = df_events.withColumn("event_id", concat_ws('_', "event_name", "event_timestamp"))
df_properties = df_events.select(
    "event_id",
    "event_name",
    "event_timestamp",
    posexplode("event_properties").alias("index", "event_properties")
)

df_entities = df_events.select(
    "event_id",
    posexplode("entities").alias("index", "entities")
)

final_df = df_properties.join(df_entities, on=["event_id", "index"]).select(
    "event_name",
    "event_properties",
    "entities",
    "event_timestamp"
)
df_final.show(truncate=False)
```

That should give the same output as per this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mamonu/8368025195272ebf4645b29392dea158).

Comment: This last step -Join on the event_id and index is not working for me. I am getting an error in this step. Error - AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`event_name`' given input columns: [event_id, event_properties, events_data.event_name, index, entities, events_data.event_timestamp]

Comment: That doesnt make sense. please check added gist with step by step results and confirm that you are seeing the same outputs at each point.

Comment: I am following step by step.Again tested it by seeing your gist. Getting same error in # Join on the event_id and index step . Error :- 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`event_name`' given input columns: [event_id, events_data.event_name, index, event_properties, events_data.event_timestamp, entities];;
'Project ['event_name, event_properties#37, entities#64, 'event_timestamp]
+- Project [event_id#20, index#36, events_data.event_name#38, events_data.event_timestamp#39, event_properties#37, entities#64]

Comment: added another way of doing it. I still dont understand why the first one doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please find the simple spark sql to flatten required columns.

```
scala> spark.table("input").toJSON.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"events":[{"entities":["entityI","entityII","entityIII"],"event_name":"start","event_properties":["property1","property2","property3"],"event_timestamp":"2022-05-01 00:00:00"},{"entities":["entityW","entityX","entityY","entityZ"],"event_name":"stop","event_properties":["propertyA","propertyB","propertyC","propertyD"],"event_timestamp":"2022-05-01 01:00:00"}]}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.sql("""
    WITH explode_events AS (
        SELECT
            inline_outer(events),
            explode_outer(entities) AS entity,
            inline_outer(transform(event_properties, e -> struct(e))) AS event_property
        FROM input)
    select
        distinct
        event_name,
        event_property,
        entity,
        event_timestamp
    from explode_events
""").show(100, false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+----------+--------------+---------+-------------------+
|event_name|event_property|entity   |event_timestamp    |
+----------+--------------+---------+-------------------+
|start     |property3     |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA     |entityX  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC     |entityY  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA     |entityY  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD     |entityY  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD     |entityX  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC     |entityZ  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property3     |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD     |entityZ  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA     |entityW  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property1     |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property2     |entityII |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB     |entityX  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC     |entityW  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyD     |entityW  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB     |entityW  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property1     |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB     |entityY  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|stop      |propertyA     |entityZ  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property3     |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyC     |entityX  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property2     |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|stop      |propertyB     |entityZ  |2022-05-01 01:00:00|
|start     |property2     |entityIII|2022-05-01 00:00:00|
|start     |property1     |entityI  |2022-05-01 00:00:00|
+----------+--------------+---------+-------------------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method from:
[PyPI flattenDF](https://pypi.org/project/pysparketl/#description)

You simply pass in your pypsark df to the function as follows:

```py
from pysparketl.dataframes import flattenDF
df_flattened = flattenDF(df)
```

That's it!